# Spring MessageSource not being used during validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I can't get my messages in messages.properties to be used during Spring validation of my form backing objects.

app-config.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties:

```
NotEmpty=This field should not be empty.
```

Form Backing Object:

```
...
  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min=6, max=25)
  private String password;
...
```

When I loop through all errors in the BindingResult and output the ObjectError's toString I get this:

```
Field error in object 'settingsForm' on field 'password': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.settingsForm.password,NotEmpty.password,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [settingsForm.password,password]; arguments []; default message [password]]; default message [may not be empty]
```

As you can see the default message is "may not be empty" instead of my message "This field should not be empty".

I do get my correct message if I inject the messageSource into a controller and output this:
messageSource.getMessage("NotEmpty", new Object [] {"password"}, "default empty message", null);

So why isn't the validation using my messages.properties?  I'm running Spring 3.1.1.  Thanks!

Comment: "Spring Validation" is just some interfaces.  Are you using javax.validation with Hibernate Validator?

Comment: I use `@Valid` (javax.validation.Valid) and in my form backing objects I use validation like `@NotEmpty` (org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty).  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NotEmpty has a message property you can set on it.  Since you're not setting it, it uses the default message.

```
@NotEmpty(message="{NotEmpty}")
```

should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes if I set the message for each @NotEmpty it uses that.  But I want it to use my messages.properties to get the default message for NotEmpty so I don't have to set it for every NotEmpty.

Comment: I've never seen what you're talking about in Spring.  Validations are field bound and should be handled as such.  If you use a default message for all fields with the same problem it makes the feedback less valuable.  An empty password is not the same as an empty username and giving a generic response such as "You have an empty field" really has no value.

Comment: I know have spring using my messages.properties file by using LocalValidatorFactoryBean and adding a validator to my mvc:annotation-driven tag.  You are right, I don't want to have a generic NotEmpty message for all fields.  And adding that message attribute to NotEmpty does work, but I was hoping it would pick up my NotEmpty.password message in my messages.properties without explicitly telling it to use NotEmpty.password.

Comment: There's no convention like that, that I know of at this time.  The system itself was designed to be extremely flexible.  If you want that functionality you could add it in yourself.

Answer (score 7):

By default HibernateValidator will get all of its messages from `/WEB-INF/classes/ValidationMessages.properties`  It reads this file directly itself, not through the Spring MessageSource.

If you want translations from a Spring Message source, set one on the [LocalValidatorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html#setValidationMessageSource%28org.springframework.context.MessageSource%29).  This does require you to manually set up a validation bean inside your dispatcher servlet, rather than rely on mvc:annotation-driven.

Comment: You can also register a custom validation bean to be a default one with '<mvc:annotation-driven validator="yourValidationFactory" />'

Answer (score 2):

When you want to set the custom message for any field using JSR 303 validations then you need to specify the bean name(LoginForm) and field name(password) in key of the message in property file. The format is CONSTRAINT_NAME.COMMAND_NAME.FIELD_NAME

```
NotEmpty.loginform.password=This field should not be empty.
```